# Understanding orthogonality in factor analysis

Tags: python, pca, factor-analysis

I have a very basic question about factor analysis based on the following code:

```
data = load_iris()
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data["data"])
fa= FactorAnalysis(n_components=2)
print(np.dot(fa.components_[0], fa.components_[1]))
```

Output:

```
-0.08777500548607892
```

Why the correlation dot product between the factors (or components) is not zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a property of the factor score estimation method. Typically, factor scores are estimated using the Regression method in most packages. The regression method does not preserve the correlations between the factors when estimating the scores. There are other score estimation methods which do preserve the correlations between the scores.

See, e.g., here for a nice overview:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255643537_Understanding_and_Using_Factor_Scores_Considerations_for_the_Applied_Researcher

(Should be open access)

Hope this helps!

PS: For more details, you could refer to the great book by Mulaik (https://www.routledge.com/Foundations-of-Factor-Analysis/Mulaik/p/book/9781420099614)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, are you saying factor analysis does not guarantee orthogonality among the factors, like PCA guarantees orthogonality among the components?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this implies. In the literature, the property of the model which is responsible for that is referred to as "factor indeterminacy" (≠ rotational indeterminacy!). It is explained very well in Mulaik's book as well. Another expert on the issue is Andre Beauducel (e.g., https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11336-005-1467-5.pdf).

Comment: How would varimax rotation affect the factor structure? How can I get orthogonal factors?

Comment: Suppose the factor model is y = LF + e. You can write y = LH*H^-1  *F+e. Where H is a rotation matrix. The rotated loadings are L* = L * H. The rotated factor scores are H^-1*F. That is, the rotated factor scores can be obtained by pre-multiplying them with the inverse of the rotation matrix. Hence, the correlatedness/uncorrelatedness of the rotated scores should not be generally "fixed" by rotation. However, you could look for "correlation preserving factors scores" – there are some proposals. For better recommendations, you should state WHY you think the scores _must_ be uncorrelated.